# Convert name to constant using switch without ugly code

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I am converting a string to a constant number and that should be done as fast as possible. If possible at compile time. It is used a lot within the code.

Is there a better way to write this type of code?

What it does is to convert the first four character into a 32 bit integer and uses that in a switch to find the constant for name.

```
/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @brief Convert type name from string to constant type value
 @code
enumType eType = type_g("int32");   assert( eType == eTypeInt32 );
eType = type_g("int8");             assert( eType == eTypeInt8 );
 @endcode
 * @param stringType type sent as string
 * @return {enumType} type constant
*/
constexpr enumType type_g( const std::string_view& stringType )
{
   enumType eType = eTypeUnknown;

   constexpr uint32_t binary_  = ((uint32_t)'b') + (uint32_t)('i' << 8) + (uint32_t)('n' << 16) + (uint32_t)('a' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t bool_  = ((uint32_t)'b') + (uint32_t)('o' << 8) + (uint32_t)('o' << 16) + (uint32_t)('l' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t double_ = ((uint32_t)'d') + (uint32_t)('o' << 8) + (uint32_t)('u' << 16) + (uint32_t)('b' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t float_ = ((uint32_t)'f') + (uint32_t)('l' << 8) + (uint32_t)('o' << 16) + (uint32_t)('a' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t i128_  = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('1' << 8) + (uint32_t)('2' << 16) + (uint32_t)('8' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t i256_  = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('2' << 8) + (uint32_t)('5' << 16) + (uint32_t)('6' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t i512_  = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('5' << 8) + (uint32_t)('1' << 16) + (uint32_t)('2' << 24);


   constexpr uint32_t int8_  = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('n' << 8) + (uint32_t)('t' << 16) + (uint32_t)('8' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t int16_ = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('n' << 8) + (uint32_t)('t' << 16) + (uint32_t)('1' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t int32_ = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('n' << 8) + (uint32_t)('t' << 16) + (uint32_t)('3' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t int64_ = ((uint32_t)'i') + (uint32_t)('n' << 8) + (uint32_t)('t' << 16) + (uint32_t)('6' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t u128_  = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('1' << 8) + (uint32_t)('2' << 16) + (uint32_t)('8' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t u256_  = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('2' << 8) + (uint32_t)('5' << 16) + (uint32_t)('6' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t u512_  = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('5' << 8) + (uint32_t)('1' << 16) + (uint32_t)('2' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t uint_  = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('i' << 8) + (uint32_t)('n' << 16) + (uint32_t)('t' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t pointer_ = ((uint32_t)'p') + (uint32_t)('o' << 8) + (uint32_t)('i' << 16) + (uint32_t)('n' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t rbinary_  = ((uint32_t)'r') + (uint32_t)('b' << 8) + (uint32_t)('i' << 16) + (uint32_t)('n' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t rstring_  = ((uint32_t)'r') + (uint32_t)('s' << 8) + (uint32_t)('t' << 16) + (uint32_t)('r' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t string_  = ((uint32_t)'s') + (uint32_t)('t' << 8) + (uint32_t)('r' << 16) + (uint32_t)('i' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t utf8_  = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('t' << 8) + (uint32_t)('f' << 16) + (uint32_t)('8' << 24);
   constexpr uint32_t utf32_  = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('t' << 8) + (uint32_t)('f' << 16) + (uint32_t)('3' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t uuid_ = ((uint32_t)'u') + (uint32_t)('u' << 8) + (uint32_t)('i' << 16) + (uint32_t)('d' << 24);

   constexpr uint32_t wstring_  = ((uint32_t)'w') + (uint32_t)('s' << 8) + (uint32_t)('t' << 16) + (uint32_t)('r' << 24);

   uint32_t uTypeName = *( uint32_t* )stringType.data(); 

   switch( uTypeName )
   {
   case binary_: eType = eTypeBinary;  break;
   case bool_: eType = eTypeBool;  break;
   case double_: eType = eTypeCDouble;  break;
   case float_: eType = eTypeCFloat;  break;

   case i128_: eType = eTypeInt128;  break;
   case i256_: eType = eTypeInt256;  break;
   case i512_: eType = eTypeInt512;  break;

   case int8_: eType = eTypeInt8;  break;
   case int16_: eType = eTypeInt16;  break;
   case int32_: eType = eTypeInt32;  break;
   case int64_: eType = eTypeInt64;  break;
   case pointer_: eType = eTypePointer;  break;

   case rbinary_: eType = eTypeRBinary;  break;
   case rstring_: eType = eTypeRString;  break;

   case string_: eType = eTypeString;  break;

   case u128_: eType = eTypeUInt128;  break;
   case u256_: eType = eTypeUInt256;  break;
   case u512_: eType = eTypeUInt512;  break;

   case uint_: 
      {
         if( stringType[4] == '8' ) eType = eTypeUInt8;
         else if( stringType[4] == '1' ) eType = eTypeUInt16;
         else if( stringType[4] == '3' ) eType = eTypeUInt32;
         else if( stringType[4] == '6' ) eType = eTypeUInt64;
         else { static_assert("invalid type name"); assert( false ); }
      }
      break;
   case uuid_: eType = eTypeGuid;  break;
   case utf8_: eType = eTypeUtf8String;  break;
   case wstring_: eType = eTypeWString;  break;
   case utf32_: eType = eTypeUtf32String;  break;
   default:
      assert(false);
   }

   return eType;
}
```

**EDIT**

*Based on tips from @Chris Uzdavinis so new solutions is like this*

```
namespace detail {
   /// helper method used to convert first four characters into 32 bit unsigned integer value
   constexpr uint32_t hash_type( std::string_view stringType )
   {
      uint32_t uHashValue = (uint32_t)stringType[0];
      uHashValue += (uint32_t)stringType[1] << 8;
      uHashValue += (uint32_t)stringType[2] << 16;
      uHashValue += (uint32_t)stringType[3] << 24;

      return uHashValue;
   }

}

/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @brief Convert type name from string to constant type value
 @code
enumType eType = type_g("int32");   assert( eType == eTypeInt32 );
eType = type_g("int8");             assert( eType == eTypeInt8 );
 @endcode
 * @param stringType type sent as string
 * @return {enumType} type constant
*/
constexpr enumType type_g( const std::string_view& stringType )
{                                                                                                  assert( stringType.length() >= 4 );
   using namespace detail;

   enumType eType = eTypeUnknown;

   uint32_t uTypeName = hash_type( stringType ); 

   switch( uTypeName )
   {
   case hash_type("bina"): eType = eTypeBinary;  break;                        // binary
   case hash_type("bool"): eType = eTypeBool;  break;                          // bool
   case hash_type("doub"): eType = eTypeCDouble;  break;                       // double
   case hash_type("floa"): eType = eTypeCFloat;  break;                        // float

   case hash_type("i128"): eType = eTypeInt128;  break;                        // int128
   case hash_type("i256"): eType = eTypeInt256;  break;                        // int254
   case hash_type("i512"): eType = eTypeInt512;  break;                        // int512

   case hash_type("int8"): eType = eTypeInt8;  break;                          // int8
   case hash_type("int1"): eType = eTypeInt16;  break;                         // int16
   case hash_type("int3"): eType = eTypeInt32;  break;                         // int32
   case hash_type("int6"): eType = eTypeInt64;  break;                         // int64
   case hash_type("poin"): eType = eTypePointer;  break;                       // pointer

   case hash_type("rbin"): eType = eTypeRBinary;  break;                       // rbinary (binary reference)
   case hash_type("rstr"): eType = eTypeRString;  break;                       // rstring (string reference)

   case hash_type("stri"): eType = eTypeString;  break;

   case hash_type("u128"): eType = eTypeUInt128;  break;                       // uint128
   case hash_type("u256"): eType = eTypeUInt256;  break;                       // uint256
   case hash_type("u512"): eType = eTypeUInt512;  break;                       // uint512

   case hash_type("uint"):                                                     // uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64
      {
         if( stringType[4] == '8' ) eType = eTypeUInt8;
         else if( stringType[4] == '1' ) eType = eTypeUInt16;
         else if( stringType[4] == '3' ) eType = eTypeUInt32;
         else if( stringType[4] == '6' ) eType = eTypeUInt64;
         else { static_assert("invalid type name"); assert( false ); }
      }
      break;
   case hash_type("uuid"): eType = eTypeGuid;  break;                          // uuid
   case hash_type("utf8"): eType = eTypeUtf8String;  break;                    // utf8
   case hash_type("wstr"): eType = eTypeWString;  break;                       // wstring
   case hash_type("utf3"): eType = eTypeUtf32String;  break;                   // uft32
   default: assert(false);
   }

   return eType;
}
```

Comment: string to constant, mapping known at compile time? So something like [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)?

Comment: To expand on that, you give gperf a table of your mapping and it will generate C code to do the lookup for you. It finds a collision-free hash function for your values that looks things up with one probe. You don't have to resort to tricks, just give it a pile of strings and enum values...

Comment: @teapot418 Is that faster compared to what I have in this `type_g` method. The names that are converted to constant values are fixed, they will not change.

Comment: branching will have its own kind of penalty, so a branchless lookup might actually be faster. In the end if performance matters always measure, and accept the fact that high performance code actually might be a bit verbose.

Comment: Related spec page 152 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a simple function to do all that repetitious work, and then call it, vastly reducing the ugliness and making it a lot more readable, just write a case for each enum as you would code it:

```
enum class enumType : uint32_t {
   eTypeBinary, eTypeBool, eTypeCDouble, eTypeCFloat, eTypeInt128, eTypeInt256,
   eTypeInt512, eTypeInt8, eTypeInt16, eTypeInt32, eTypeInt64, eTypePointer,
   eTypeRBinary, eTypeRString, eTypeString, eTypeUInt128, eTypeUInt256, eTypeUInt512,
   eTypeUInt8, eTypeUInt16, eTypeUInt32, eTypeUInt64, eTypeGuid, eTypeUtf8String,
   eTypeWString, eTypeUtf32String, eTypeUnknown,
};

constexpr uint32_t myHash(std::string_view sv) {
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sv.size(); ++i) {
        result += sv[i] << (8*i); 
    }
    return result;
}

constexpr enumType type_g(std::string_view stringType )
{
   using enum enumType;

   switch(myHash(stringType))
   {
   case myHash("bina"): return eTypeBinary;
   case myHash("bool"): return eTypeBool;
   case myHash("doub"): return eTypeCDouble;
   // ...
   default:
      throw "unhandled"; // compile time err if reached in constexpr
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this performant?  It would make sense to me to at least precompute the (invariant) hashes.

Comment: @Paul Sanders The hash method is not executed in runtime, the compiler is using the hash method to calculate key value at compile time.

Comment: @PaulSanders as a "case" value in a switch _must_ be a compile time constant, if it compiles, the hashes for them, _will_ be done at compile time.  The `myHash` call in the switch on the argument `stringType` may or may not be a compile time constant, depending on the context the function is called (in a constant expression or not.)  Similarly, the "switch logic" resolving the cases is either done at compile time, or at runtime, also depending on constant expression (or not) context of caller.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Asleep at the wheel :)

Comment: As you can see in this example, it optimizes away _entirely_ if given a constant expression:  https://godbolt.org/z/Wh3xazz9P . It's also worth noting that the original code does not check bounds so can have undefined behavior if the passed-in string_view is too short and bytes are read after the end.  With the constexpr version, it is a compile time error to go out of bounds.  While at compile time it has zero cost for runtime, the runtime version calls strlen(), while the OP code does not, so it is slightly less "performant" but safer.